# Print numbers in a string in specific format using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was to be able to create a file using python which has data in the specific format shown below. It starts from 00000# where `#` is `1` and goes all the way to `100000`. The same number is present in each line before and after the text `My Team`.

```
#output file
000001 My Team 000001
000002 My Team 000002
...all the way to
100000 My Team 100000
```

I am not sure on how to do this format creation in python. I know it is something simple but I am a bit lost on how to proceed. I am very new to python and I would appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance on this.

Thank you to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) added in python 3.6:

```
PADDING = 6

with open('test.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for i in range(1, 100001):
        print(f'{i:0{PADDING}d} My Team {i:0{PADDING}d}', file=fh)
```

OUTPUT:

```
000001 My Team 000001
000002 My Team 000002
...
100000 My Team 100000
```

Another method would be to use [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) (zfill stands from zero-fill):

```
>>> i = 1
>>> f'{str(i).zfill(PADDING)} My Team {str(i).zfill(PADDING)}'
000001 My Team 000001
```

Comment: Just use [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)

Comment: @DeepSpace isn't it slower than `f-strings`? Nonetheless, I prefer `f-string` because it gives me more flexibility.

Comment: I don't know, but even if it is, it is going to be in a very small margin, and `f'{str(i).zfill(padding)} My Team {str(i).zfill(padding)}'` is much more readable. Of course, if you save `str(i).zfill(padding)` as a variable the speed difference (if it even exists) will be smaller

Comment: Why are you assuming you can not use `f-string` with `str.zfill`? `f-string`s work with any expression

Comment: there seems to be syntax error in the f string statement.

Comment: @Anna Make sure you are using Python >= 3.6

Comment: @DeepSpace Sorry for the ambiguity, I was referring to string formatting options provided by `f-string`. While I concur, `str(i).zfill(padding)` makes it more readable, I will still have to convert an integer to string explicitly, whereas if it were already string I wouldn't have minded much. Also I find `zfill` to be a very specific method meant to do just a single thing.

Comment: @DeepSpace nonetheless, I will add it for the sake of completeness, I guess it is upto OP's preference.

Comment: I just did some timings, and even `f'{str(i).zfill(PADDING)} My Team {str(i).zfill(PADDING)}'` (without caching `str(i).zfill(PADDING)`) is faster

Comment: `"Also I find zfill to be a very specific method meant to do just a single thing"` I'm not sure what you are trying to say here. `zfill` is doing exactly what OP is trying to to do here. Also, **every good** method is meant to just a single thing, and do it well

Comment: @DeepSpace Of course, it exactly does the job, I meant I, personally, don't like `zfill` because of its very narrow scope of usability, it is too much of a syntax sugar, hence I feel one shouldn't bother remembering the method at all. Of course, entirely my own take.

Comment: No string method apart from zfill can be achieved with str.format. If str.format is already present and it can do the job well, don't see why zfill was needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to make sure that a number always has six digits, you can do that with something like this

```py
def leadingZeros(num, length):
    out_str = str(num);
    while len(out_str) < length:
        out_str = "0" + out_str;
    return out_str;
```

Comment: Please, drop the semicolons. Also, this is exactly why we have [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting to achieve this

```py
output_string = ''.join([f'{i:06d} My Team {i:06d}\n'for i in range(1, 100001)])
```

Alternatively using `zfill`

```py
output_string = ''.join([f'{str(i).zfill(6)} My Team {str(i).zfill(6)}\n'for i in range(1, 100001)])
```

Comment: Just use [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)

Comment: Why, does zfil has advantages?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to print the contents of the file which are already in that format then**

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
      file_data=f.read()
      l=file_data.split("\n")
      print(*l)
```

**If you want create a file like that then you can use, place the file the same directory as you code is in**

```
with open('test.txt','w') as myfile:
for i in range(1,100001):
    print("{:0>6d} My team {:0>6d}".format(i,i),file=myfile)
```